# Why do we need different models of thermal relaxation noise for $T2>T1$ and $T2<T1$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, noise

Noisy quantum channels are in generally described by the operator-sum representation with kraus operators (see eg. in Nielsen,Chuang). But for the thermal relaxation error different modeling used for when T1< T2 and T1>T2 for example in the [implementation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.noise.thermal_relaxation_error.html#qiskit.providers.aer.noise.thermal_relaxation_error) of the quantum computing simulation package qiskit and as described in II.C of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.02109):
for T2<T1 kraus operators are used with $K_0 = \sqrt(p_I)I , K_1=\sqrt(p_Z)Z, K_2=\sqrt(p_{reset0})|1><0|, K_3=\sqrt(p_{reset1})|1><1| $, so that the effect of the channel is $$ N( \rho )=\sum_k K_k \rho K_k^\dagger$$
For T2>T1 a Choi-matrix representation is used with the 4x4 Choi-matrix C and the effect of the quantum channel $$N(\rho)=tr_1(C(\rho^T \otimes I))$$

I do understand the two representations by themselves. But my question is why one makes this distinction between the two regions.
Is this due to the Choi-matrix being more efficient to compute? So, is the Kraus operator representation the more general one and the easier Choi-matrix can be used as well in the region of T1<T2?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please avoid external links and try to write a question as self-contained as possible. Not only would it make things easier for the people willing to help, but links could break in the future, making the question impossible to understand. Thank you.